# Problem with connecting to REST Api by HTTPS from Xamarin forms - Android phone

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created Xamarin forms app and .net core REST api. What I managed to do is to connect my Android phone with USB, deploy Xamarin forms app on it, run REST API on IIS EXPRESS from Visual studio and hit it from Xamarin app on the phone by HTTP by using HttpClient class.

What I didn't manage to do is to do the same and hit the REST api by HTTPS. Here is what I tried and which point I reached:

1. I configured port forwarding in chrome and managed to hit my local api by using web browser on my phone. So, I proved that hitting https://localhost:someport/somecontroller/someaction works.
2. I also constructed HttpClient object (client = new HttpClient()) and managed to make successful get request to https://www.google.com from my Xamarin app. So, I proved that HTTPS to Google works.
3. Next step is to hit my api from my app. 
   I installed self signed certificate on my pc and instantiated HttpClient class in the app like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; } });
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

With this code I always get Connection refused exception on httpClient.SendAsync(request). What is interesting is that this code works when hitting service from UWP, just not from Android phone (I didn't try Ios). Another interesting situation is that if I instantiate HttpClient in any other way then with parameterless constructor (new HttpClient()), for example (new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler())) then even my previously successful HTTP case won't work either.

According to all written, summary is that all cases work except using HTTPS from Android to local PC in order to hit REST api. Any idea or hint would be helpful.

Comment: If you are using local/127.0.0.1 on the Android emul. then it is the device itself, not your PC host. Try using 10.0.2.2 on the Android emul to reach it's PC host.

Comment: I am using real device, not emulator, and when using port forwarding that I set up through chrome developer console, which recognizes my connected phone, than phone hits actually my machine. Proof for that is that when I open chrome on my phone and hit the same address like in my app, I really hit the REST api on my machine.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed cert?

Comment: Yes, but, if I am not wrong, I guess this line of code handles that case: var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; } }); At least it did in asp.net core projects.

Comment: 1) Which API level are u getting the error on? 2) What is the full exception (i.e. including the innerexception) AND 3) what is reported in `logcat` ? (fyi, you can not bypass the OSs protections, i.e. iOS forces you to deal w/ self-signed certs as an **untrusted** application and you have to flag the app as such)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that the Android device does not know local device. Windows machine knows it hence you can access it in UWP.

One method is to connect all devices to same network and use ip address to access localhost. Further explanation is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services).

But I suggest that you use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) it's much hassle free. Tunnel your localhost through their domain and use the allocated uri instead of localhost. I use it myself for the same purpose, works great.

Their docs is super friendly. If you have any trouble comment here.

Comment: That is true, just it is not actual problem in this case. As I wrote in the question I managed to hit my machine with localhost and port forwarding both through my app and chrome on the phone. Just, couldn't make it to use HTTPS, but I succeeded with HTTP. The question is where am I getting wrong with HTTPS.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with HTTPS on ios or android and after 3 hours of trying stumbled on this post. NGROK was genius and worked perfectly. Great example of needing to step back and think through the problem with a fresh mind.